# Can I prevent the automatic casting from string to XName?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Being a bit of a purist, I hate seeing string constants spread through out my code:

```
var x = element.Attribute("Key");
```

I like to have the them stored as a single referenced constant, and I like the approach I first saw in Eric White's **XmlPowerTools**:

```
public class MyNamespace {
  public static readonly XNamespace Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/schema";
  public static readonly XName Key = Namespace + "Key";
}
```

and use:

```
var x = element.Attribute(MyNamespace.Key);
```

The beauty of this is that I can easily find all references to these `static` fields using Visual Studio or Resharper and not have to wade through each found instance of the string "Key", which one can imagine is used in many unrelated places.

So, I have a legacy project that I want to convert to using the `XName` approach and need to find all occurrences of where a string has been used instead of an `XName`. I figure that if I could stop the automatic conversion of string to `XName`, the compiler would pick up all these occurrences for me.

I used a regex in the find:

```
(Element|Attribute|Ancestor)s?\("
```

which picked up those constructs, but then I found:

```
if (element.Name == "key")
```

and wondered what else I was going to miss.

The question is, how do I stop the automatic conversion of string to `XName`, or what other approach is there to locating all occurrences of string that should be `XName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there's a way you can potentially *fix* it, but not prevent it (without wrapping the XName library).

Remove the reference to the `XName` library, create your own XName class with the same namespace, but don't provide the string implicit conversion. 
Try to compile, and you will find all places where a string is assigned to an `XName`.

You may have to play around with it to properly compile (for example, chucking your new class into a separate library, having *it* and *only it* reference the `XName` library, and subclass the original, so it doesn't fail to compile when using the object in the API).

Once you've fixed it all up, then delete the class and add the XName library back.

To prevent it in the future, you could write a class which provides implicit conversion to XName, but not from string. Unfortunately, though, you'd need to change your whole codebase to use your wrapper.

Comment: I did indeed write a local version of the required classes and stub out the methods just so the compiler would locate them. That's my purpose for now. In future I will ensure the XName constants are defined when the xsd is created and watch for misuses in code reviews.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit operators can't be *stopped*.

In the other hand, taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname(v=vs.110).aspx):

> XName does not contain any public constructors. Instead, this class
>   provides an implicit conversion from String that allows you to create
>   an XName

Alternatively, you could turn this code:

```
if (element.Name == "key")
```

...into:

```
   XName key = "key";

   if(element.Name == key)
```

BTW, I feel that you're going to overcomplicate things just to get more searchability, while the goal of coding programming languages is producing *executable code* and you should code as simple as possible to increase maintainability and quality...

Comment: Your second code snippet is exactly what I am wanting to do. I just looking for a quick way to locate them all.

Comment: @axeman I believe that there's no way to get what you want, I would say that you'll need to live with this "limitation"... :D

Comment: Also, the reason for putting string constants into a single location is to reduce the likelihood of spelling/typing errors. IMHO duplicate string constants are just as bad as duplicate code. My aim is to have correct, maintainable executable code. :-) Having XName constants also allows for seeing the structure of large solutions and in which assemblies certain namespaces are used.

Comment: I think I'll just have to manually wade through the hundreds of instances! Thanks for confirming my worst fears!